# Help with $\int_{t_0}^{t_{0}+h}\delta(t)\,dt=h\delta\left(t_0+\frac12h\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the definition that $\,\,\,\,\delta (t)=0.15-0.03t\,\,\,\,\,\,$ for $\,\,\,\,0\le t\le1$

in a textbook the following is shown but I'm trying to understand how they get from the LHS to the RHS:

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_{0}+h}\delta(t)\,dt=h\delta\left(t_0+\frac12h\right)$$

How and why is the $h$ term being used on the RHS when on the LHS the function is (or at least I think it is) being integrated with respect to $t$? Am I not seeing something that is fundamental?

The book goes on to the next step

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_{0}+h}\delta(t)\,dt=h\delta\left(t_0+\frac12h\right)=h\left[0.15-0.03\left(t_0+\frac12h\right) \right]$$

I was jumping straight from the LHS to the following

$$=0.15t-0.03 \left( \frac12\right)t^2$$

Please can you tell me why that is wrong? I'm confused over the use of $h$ and $t$.

Comment: Just plug in the bounds of integration…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a definite integral
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_{0}+h}\delta(t)\,dt$$

But as i see when you integrated it you didn't consider the integral limits (i mean upper and lower boundaries).
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_0+h} (0.15-0.03 t) dt =0.15t\:|_{t_0}^{t_0+h}-0.015t^2\:|_{t_0}^{t_0+h}\\= h (-0.015 h-0.03 t_0+0.15)=h\left[0.15-0.03\left(t_0+\frac12h\right) \right]$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the function in the integrand is linear, the area under the curve (the definite integral) is the sum of a rectangle and a triangle.  this can be rearranged into the area of a rectangle, with width equal to the width of the interval and height equal to the height at the midpoint of the interval, which is exactly what you've got.

Go through the rectangle/triangle geometry to prove it to yourself without actually having to integrate and evaluate (like the other answer).